# access input form in angular and insert data on it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

I'm trying to create edit option in angular, but what i need is when i click edit data of this selected item send to form and then display it in inputs form with the ability to edit them

what i did is send the id in the endpoint , then using api i return this data, but now i need to display it in the form , but what i didn't know that how can i access the inputs form and write on it ?

this my **html** code :

```
  <form class="form" [formGroup]="editStudentform">
    <div class="user-box">
      <input name="serialNumber" required="" formControlName="serialNumber" type="number"> invoice.serialNumber
      <label>serial Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="user-box">
      <input name="status" required="" formControlName="status" type="text">
      <label>status</label>
    </div>
    <div class="user-box">
      <input name="customerSerialNumber" required="" formControlName="customerSerialNumber" type="text">
      <label>customer Serial Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="user-box">
      <input name="employeeSerialNumber" required="" formControlName="employeeSerialNumber" type="text">
      <label>employee Serial Number</label>
    </div>
    <a routerLink="/invoics" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="editStudent()" type="submit" >
```

and this is mu **typescript** code :

export class UpdateInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {

```
  editStudentform: FormGroup = this._formbuilder.group({
    serialNumber : ['' , Validators.required],
    status : ['' , Validators.required],
    customerSerialNumber : ['' , Validators.required],
    employeeSerialNumber : ['' , Validators.required]

  });
  id :number = -1;
  constructor(private _formbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _http: HttpClient,
    private route:ActivatedRoute
    ) { }
    invoice : any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
   this._http
   .get('http://localhost:8085/invoice/get-invoice/'+this.id)
   .subscribe((response: any) => {
     this.invoice = response;
   });

// i think i should write smth here
  }

  editStudent(){
    let serialNumber = this.editStudentform.get('serialNumber')?.value;
    let status = this.editStudentform.get('status')?.value;
    let customerSerialNumber = this.editStudentform.get('customerSerialNumber')?.value;
    let employeeSerialNumber = this.editStudentform.get('employeeSerialNumber')?.value;

    let url = "http://localhost:8085/invoice/update/";
    let obj = {serialNumber:serialNumber , status:status , customerSerialNumber:customerSerialNumber,employeeSerialNumber:employeeSerialNumber}
    this._http.put(url,obj).subscribe(data=>{console.log(data)
    alert("row edited");
    })

  }

}
```

This api response example in postman:

[image]

Comment: this.editStudentform.get('customerSerialNumber')?.setValue(valueYouWant)

Comment: it's return error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serialNumber')`

Comment: when i put `.setValue(this.invoice.serialNumber)`

Comment: Means this.invoice is not defined, maybe you did not receive the response from your API call?

Comment: I think it too, but i tsested it in postman and it's worked, where is the issue ?

Comment: @Salketer has provided the solution, you just need to make sure you put it inside of the subscriber callback (so you only use it after you get it from the API)

Comment: Postman does test the response of the API, but you'll have to make sure your subscribe handler has ran before you use this.invoice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should create a class/interface for the invoice and don't use any iff possible ,

Than , in the subscription you could do something like this.

```
this.editStudentForm.patchValue({
 serialNumber : response.serialNumber,
status : response.status
customerSerialNumber : response.costumerSerialNumber : 
employeeSerialNumber : response.employeeSerialNumber 
})
```